# How to transfer table column into array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-table

I want to separate table `column` into array format like this:

{[A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,B,C]}

Now I only know how to transfer table row into string:

A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,C

How to set table `column` into array?

My code below here:

```js
$(function(){
    
    var letters = $("#selectable td").map(function() {
       return $(this).text();
  }).get();
    console.log(letters);
});
```

```css
#selectable tr .ui-selected{ 
  background: #F39814; 
  color: white; 
}
#selectable{ 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  width: 450px; 
}
#selectable td{ 
  margin: 3px; 
  padding: 1px; 
  float: left; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 80px; 
  font-size: 4em; 
  text-align: center;
}
#selectable th{ 
  margin: 3px; 
  padding: 1px; 
  float: left; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 20px; 
  font-size: 1em; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<table id="selectable">
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<tr>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    var letters = []
    $('#selectable tr').map(function(index_tr, item_tr){
        $(item_tr).find('td').map(function(index_td, item_td){
            letters[index_td] = letters[index_td] || []
            letters[index_td].push($(item_td).text())
     })
    })
    alert(JSON.stringify(letters))
});
```

```css
#selectable tr .ui-selected{ 
  background: #F39814; 
  color: white; 
}
#selectable{ 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  width: 450px; 
}
#selectable td{ 
  margin: 3px; 
  padding: 1px; 
  float: left; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 80px; 
  font-size: 4em; 
  text-align: center;
}
#selectable th{ 
  margin: 3px; 
  padding: 1px; 
  float: left; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 20px; 
  font-size: 1em; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="selectable">
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<tr>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Is it possible to transfer [["A","B","C"],["A","B","C"],["A","B","C"],["A","B","C"]] into {[A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,B,C]} ??

Comment: @S.P. {[A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,B,C]} is not JSON format, if you want you can join it with string method

Comment: Ok I see! Thanks again!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
    
    var letters = [];
    $("#selectable tr.content").each(function() {
  letters.push($(this).find('td').map(function() {
       return $(this).text();}).get());
 });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(letters));
});
```

```css
#selectable tr .ui-selected{ 
  background: #F39814; 
  color: white; 
}
#selectable{ 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  width: 450px; 
}
#selectable td{ 
  margin: 3px; 
  padding: 1px; 
  float: left; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 80px; 
  font-size: 4em; 
  text-align: center;
}
#selectable th{ 
  margin: 3px; 
  padding: 1px; 
  float: left; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 20px; 
  font-size: 1em; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<table id="selectable">
<tr>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>3</th>
  <th>4</th>
</tr>
<tr class="content">
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">A</td>
</tr>
<tr class="content">
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">B</td>
</tr>
<tr class="content">
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
  <td class="ui-state-default">C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to make it looks like as column data not the row data like this: {[A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,B,C],[A,B,C]}  not  the row [["A","A","A","A"],["B","B","B","B"],["C","C","C","C"]], but thanks for the answer!!! :)